# can I pass a value to a sibling component without saving it as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have some bootstrap vue cards with a v-for statement, one of my tags returns a value based on the current iteration of v-for. I want to pass this value to another tag, if I save it as a variable before passing it then all iterations end up sharing the same variables but I don't want that.

```
<b-card-group v-for="(element, i) in array" :key="index">
    <b-card>
        <tag @update="updateFunction()" />
        <otherTag />
    <b-card />
<b-card-group />
```

I want the variable to be specific to the current iteration so future iterations won't have access to it.

Comment: What variable? "my tags returns a value" -> where is that?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking two questions, so I am going to answer them in turn.

---

The main problem you seem to have is that you do not know how to differentiate between each card in your `updateFunction` function. The easiest way to make your `updateFunction` context-aware, is by putting an arrow function that takes one argument, and calls updateFunction with two arguments.

Your update handler would look something like this. You take the index of the card you are trying to update, and the value that was sent from a sibling.

```
methods: {
  handleUpdate(index, val) {
    this.$set(this.cards, index, val);
  }
}
```

You then use an arrow function to make the update handler context-aware:

```
<tag @update="(value) => handleUpdate(index, value)" />
```

[image: Edit Context-aware update handler]

---

As for the question in the title of your problem description: If you are passing a value as a prop, you have two options. You either put a literal in the prop (e.g. `:my-prop="5"`), or you put a variable in the prop (e.g. `:my-prop="myVariable"`). The first one obviously doesn't allow you to change the value, so that is not very useful here. The second one pulls the data directly from the state of the parent component. It is thus not possible to pass data as a prop without it being saved in the parent component.

As shown above, that doesn't mean you can't have different data for different iterations of your `v-for` though.

There are other methods of sharing data between siblings, which is especially useful in larger applications, by using a vuex store. This will allow you to abstract away data in useful "chunks" (or modules), allowing you to interact with it using getters, mutations and actions. You can find more information [using the official documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).